# Having exception in Win Form Application because SQL query takes too long time to execute

Tags: sql-server, winforms, ado.net

I have millions records in a database. When I fetch with conditions that are not indexed, it takes 2-5 minutes SQL query to be executed.
But, C# windows form application gives exception because it thinks SQL server is not responding it. 
What is the solution?

Comment: You can change the connection timeout to 0

Comment: May you give example code?

Comment: command.CommandTimeout = 0;

Comment: Firstly, that mean you have a problem with your query you can try to optimize your query using an index and by deleting the columns you do not need, if the problem persist you can set your CommandTimeout to 0 , your command will wait indefinitely until your query return a result.

Comment: Use proper indexes on the table... Use pagination to retrieve only page of data. Retrieve only needed columns from the database.

Comment: I know indexing is solid solution. But I dont want to waste time and space for indexing 15 GB / 15*50 million records. Some columns are already indexed though.
I just added command.CommandTimeout = 0 to the c# form app. I hope it solves the problem. Thank you.

Comment: I think you would be best fixing the query itself it it's taking that long to load. Although setting the CommandTimeout may be a workaround, waiting 2-5 minutes for a query is unexpected.

Comment: Fix your query first, 5 minutes is enormous long and change your connection timeout to 0 and i suggested to you use try catch when fecthing to prevent other errors.